# Skid plate manufacturing detailed Schematic

Tags: manufacturing-engineering

I need to make a skid plate for my vehicle, Nissan Xtrail T31

Is there a site where i can get detailed manufacturing sheet for my specific car model ?
The schematic should include detailed dimensions so it's easier to make the finished product.

Please see attached images to see a sample of how i want the final product to be.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Why would the manufacturer of that plate just **give** you the details to make it? Of courseb your simple solution is to get under your vehicle, establish a centre line and measure the location points.

Answer (score 1):

OH, I know what you want to do. You want to make a plate to cover the whole undercarriage to protect everything underneath. An excellent place to start is The Haynes owner manual and manufacturing information. Whenever I work on cars I always use the Haynes's book's as they explain a lot about the vehicle, these days they have a website. You can get a membership and get any information on any vehicle and how to fix it or whatever you need, you will for sure find  it there.

Comment: Thanks Mathew, i've checked their website and it seems promising.
I tried checking the technical drawings section but it seems i have to purchase the online manual to have access to the drawings.

This makes a good start so far, again thanks for sharing haynes Mat. Cheers

Comment: Yes, that's the bad part about it. I wish I can fine you something better for free. Sometimes that's not always  the case, Sometimes you have to pay for it and hope for the best.